# Can two cellphones act like radar/sonar with each other?

Tags: android, gps, smartphone, locationmanager

I was wondering if it were possible to have two cellphones interact with one another like a radar/sonar device to be able to find one another or be accurate within maybe 500 yards or so? Also, if there is a way to do it without the GPS or connecting to a cell tower (like being indoors or out in a desert)? Are there any technologies resident in a cellphone that can bounce off each other link radar to find one another basically without the need for gps/cell tower triangulation? Im trying to create a fun app similar to the Ghostbuster's EKG Meter :-)

Comment: for limited distance like 100m , you can try bluetooth connections

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wifi direct can reach further than Bluetooth and also transmit data faster http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/wifip2p.html

But 500 yards seems to be too far for the technology reside in the current mobile phone.

Answer (score 2):

No.

Even going through all the other ways a phone could possibly connect to another phone(bluetooth, ad-hoc networking, wireless network...), you have no frame of reference to calculate distance. You couldn't possibly "ping" another phone, and derive distance from that ping like you could with sonar/radar. You need another fixed point to derive the distance like you could with triangulation, or 2 fixed points with GPS.

Sorry.. doesn't sound feasible.

Comment: What about something similar to what shopkick is doing? one phone sends out a signal, and when the other phone detects it (not sure the range factor here) it resends the signal back (so on and so forth till the rate at which they were sent/received is shorter).

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Wifi or Bluetooth for this (there is a reason why when installing a pro-network, they do wave propagation models of the building). Sound won't work also, as the sampling rates in iPhone are limited as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382079/iphone-ultrasound-detection-more-than-22-khz).